# iOS Swift - How to implement set of images in TableView Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I need to create a set of images. Each set has a header and footer with buttons. How should I implement this? As UICollectionView, where each set - is section with header, footer and images. Or as UITableView - where each set of a Cell?

So each set can contain 3 - 9 images.

I have found the solution https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout, but i think it is too havy form my task.

Set with 3 images - has own reuse identifier CellSet3

Set with 4 images - with reuse identifier CellSet4 and so on..

Or is there a better way to solve?

[image]

Comment: I'd use UICollectionView with section header and section footer and different reusable cells. It is easier because you can modify cell sizes with UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Comment: So each Post will be as UICollectionView Section? I think it is too complicated. If i load 100 Post - i need 100 Sections?

Comment: Yes, why not? it shouldn't more difficult than using a UITableView. But anyway it is just an opinion. :) You could do it with both. I almost always choose UICollectionView because it is more flexible.